# Unable to play the RTMP url in AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, rtmp

```
- (void)playMethod {


 NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"rtmp://54.206.31.70:1935/CVIEW_alpha/24"];


    player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
    controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    [self addChildViewController:controller];
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];

    //to rotate to the landscape on click of play button
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:@(UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) forKey:@"orientation"];
    [UINavigationController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];

    //to open the view
    controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,667,375);
    controller.player = player;
    controller.showsPlaybackControls = YES;

    // to add the back button on player
    UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button1 addTarget:self
                action:@selector(backMethod)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button1 setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(50.0, CGRectGetMinY(controller.view.frame)+10, 160.0, 40.0);
    button1.tag = 1001;
    [self.view addSubview:button1];
    [controller.view  bringSubviewToFront:button1];
    [player pause];
    [player play];
}
```

I am trying to play the above URL in AVPlayer and getting the following errors.

> 2018-06-08 14:55:00.326842+0530 vedio[14773:4486922] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002
>   2018-06-08 14:55:00.605227+0530 vedio[14773:4485935] [] <<<< AVOutputDeviceDiscoverySession (FigRouteDiscoverer) >>>> -[AVFigRouteDiscovererOutputDeviceDiscoverySessionImpl outputDeviceDiscoverySessionDidChangeDiscoveryMode:]: Setting device discovery mode to DiscoveryMode_None (client: vedio)
>   2018-06-08 14:55:00.652598+0530 vedio[14773:4485935] [] <<<< AVOutputDeviceDiscoverySession (FigRouteDiscoverer) >>>> -[AVFigRouteDiscovererOutputDeviceDiscoverySessionImpl outputDeviceDiscoverySessionDidChangeDiscoveryMode:]: Setting device discovery mode to DiscoveryMode_Presence (client: vedio)
>   2018-06-08 14:55:01.013628+0530 vedio[14773:4485935] [App] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction
>   2018-06-08 14:55:01.013766+0530 vedio[14773:4485935] [App] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction

Comment: I think you need to add `rtmp://` in info.plist -> url schema

Comment: @MahendraGP still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

AVPlayer does not have support for rtmp. You must use a different player, or protocol.